# Jquery UI - Background flashes on hovered/active button in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

Having the task to re-desing an intranet website, I've decided to style-up all the buttons using Jquery UI, and using the .button() method.

```
$('button').button(); // Simplified Code
```

The button changes the background color and the gloss when hovered (making use of a theme).

It works fine in every browser, except IE.

The issue is: the background goes away for a split-second, and then returns, making the button all 'flashy'.

JQ ThemeRoller Demo, however, works fine (no 'flashing' there). (Some other demos have the sami issue though.)

What can be causing the issue? (I've tried changing the theme, etc) 
-Thanks!

Comment: where have you placed your css/js scripts?

Comment: I doubt this is the cause of the issue; they're located in HEAD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think image caching is the issue here. Do you use jquery ui icons on the button ? ( Jquery ui use some background png images for construct buttons and icons )

Then have a look :

http://suburbia.org.uk/blog/2009/08/04/074709.html and 
http://www.zachleat.com/web/dear-ie6-please-cache-my-images/

Try to use document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true); for IE versions.

Comment: I dont use UI the icons; however, I make use of backgroud-image in order to give the button a 3-d look. 
This backgroud-image change is exactly what is causing the flashing.
Firefox renders it correctly, fyi.

Comment: You can see it for yourself:
http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137727/Buttons
Open in IE (IE8 too), select a theme in the demo ('Le Frog' demonstrates it well).

Comment: Did you use  document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true) ?